# Inserting XML into MySQL

Tags: mysql, xml

I am trying to insert some XML into a MySQL table but am having some trouble because I only want to insert certain attributes and not all the attributes in the XML file.

Here is subset of the XML:

`<rosters>
    <team id="1" team_name="Ravens">`
        `<players>
            <player id="28" jersey_number="34" first_name="Joe" last_name="Flacco"/>
            <player id="4" jersey_number="43" first_name="Ray" last_name="Lewis"/>
        </players>
    </team>
    <team id="2" team_name="Broncos">
        <players>
            <player id="9" jersey_number="5" first_name="Peyton" last_name="Manning"/>
        </players>
    </team>
</rosters>`

I want to loop through each team and insert the players on the team with certain attributes.

These would be the columns in the MySQL table: player_id(primary key and autoincrement), first_name, last_name, and the player's respective team.

This would be the desired table after inserting the attributes:

```
player_id, first_name, last_name,   team
        1,        Joe,    Flacco,  Ravens
        2,        Ray,     Lewis,  Ravens
        3,     Peyton,   Manning, Broncos
```

I am new to XML and most of the answers I have found usually insert all elements into a single table. It would be much appreciated if someone could help me with my specific question or direct me to a resource.

Comment: What are you using to insert this data into a MySQL database? Do you have any code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`LOAD XML`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/load-xml.html) is what you are looking for.

Similarly to the [`LOAD DATA`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/load-data.html) command (just replace `DATA` with `XML` in the example provided):

> You can also discard an input value by assigning it to a user variable and not assigning the variable to a table column:
>
> ```
> LOAD DATA INFILE 'file.txt'
> INTO TABLE t1
> (column1, @dummy, column2, @dummy, column3);
> ```

Comment: Thanks. I was able to insert the desired attributes and was able to specify the ones I wanted.

Comment: Thanks @user3637624, I didn't know this was possible.